# flipview virtualization windows store xaml c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have some problem with flipview control. What I have inside my flipview itemtemplate is Image and textblock control.
If I make textblock of first Image visible than it also shows up in 4,6,8... item of flipview.

By searching on some forums I tried to figure out that problem was with `VirtualizingStackPanel` . It was set to `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`

I tried following things but not getting the solution:

1. Set `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"` , It stop recycling the control but when I come back to that it disappears from the first items also

2.

```
<FlipView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</FlipView.ItemsPanel>
```

This solves the problem of repeating the controls , but when I rebind the `flipview` `itemsource` than it `throws exception.`

Comment: What type of collection are you using to hold the data? An ObservableCollection? A list? An IncrementalLoadingCollection?

Comment: Using List for holding data. Also tried ObservableCollection it also throws exception while rebind in case 2.

Comment: Try using a CollectionViewSource with an ObservableCollection backend.

Comment: Already I am using CollectionViewSource.

Comment: If that's the case, then you likely shouldn't be rebinding the FlipView ItemsSource, but instead the CVS's source.

Comment: I tried both the way, but still having problem with it.

Comment: Hmmmm... Have you tried not replacing the `ItemSource`, but instead simply changing the data in the `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: That's really good solution, but app crashes when there are more items like 200 in the observablecollection(in scenario 2). any solution for this ?

Comment: What kind of crash is it? If you are using a StackPanel, then it is drawing all 200 elements at once. You may want to look into an IncrementalLoadingObservableCollection.

Comment: when I load more items like 200 apps automatically get crash.
As you mention for incremental loading but as per my knowledge flipview is not supporting incremental loading as mention in this thread.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/12c8f6df-9d21-4239-8cab-f904211302de/flipview-and-isupportincrementalloading?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: You can manually increase the load each time by listening to the `SelectionChanged` event. You'll want to remove items from the beginning as you progress and from the end as you backtrack (if you do backtrack).

Comment: Can you give me your solution for this problem? Please.
Because when I removed previous items and add to the end - I have flickering and shift in view. 
Thanks!

Comment: @NikitaBondarenko I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, and why you are adding previous items at the end. I need to search for the sample I created, but I don't think that will fit for your scenario. If you can share me your sample project,I can help you by doing necessary changes.